# Text File Reading Does Not Return Accented Characters

Tags: c#, uwp, character-encoding

I am working on a UWP application that needs to read text files sent by clients. Files are plain text usually created in Notepad. These files are read perfectly. The problem is when they create the file in other software, such as Microsoft Word, and save it as plain text. This is the code I am using to read the files.

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
                DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
                byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
                rtbText.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageDialog msgDlg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
                await msgDlg.ShowAsync();
            }
```

Comment: Are the files being saved using UTF8 encoding?

Comment: If your code can read files saved by Notepad, but not those saved by Word (as plain text), then you can probably figure out the problem by comparing the contents of the two files. Put some accented characters at the beginning of the text. Open them both in a eye-level editor and comparing if there is a BOM, and how the characters are encoded

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ "There Ain’t No Such Thing As Plain Text. If you have a string, in memory, in a file, or in an email message, you have to know what encoding it is in or you cannot interpret it or display it to users correctly."

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica, probably not, because reading the file returns incorrect characters, such as �. Unfortunately, I have no control over how clients create files.

Comment: @Christopher, I really liked the article, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ Flydog57, I now know that the files generated in Notepad are in UTF-8 without BOM and the files generated in Microsoft Word are in iso-8859-1 (codepage 28591). The problem now is to identify each encoding programmatically. Any suggestion?

Comment: @JoseAfonso You can delcare that the input has to be a specific Encoding. Paradox Games for example insist on mod manifest files being UTF-8 with BOM. On any other format? Will not be read. Error message in the log | If you can not fix it to one ecoding, the best solution is the HTML Guestimate. With a longterm goal of phasing it out for XML/HTML style "anotate the Encoding in the file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool class that needs to install the `UDE.CSharp.UWP` nuget package, it helps me.

**Code**

```cs
public class FileEncoding
{
    const int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 128 * 1024;

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to detect the file encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputStream">The input stream.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultIfNotDetected">The default encoding if none was detected.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Encoding DetectFileEncoding(Stream inputStream, Encoding defaultIfNotDetected = null)
    {
        var det = new FileEncoding();
        det.Detect(inputStream);
        return det.Complete() ?? defaultIfNotDetected;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to detect the file encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputData">The input data.</param>
    /// <param name="start">The start.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The count.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultIfNotDetected">The default encoding if none was detected.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Encoding DetectFileEncoding(byte[] inputData, int start, int count, Encoding defaultIfNotDetected = null)
    {
        var det = new FileEncoding();
        det.Detect(inputData, start, count);
        return det.Complete() ?? defaultIfNotDetected;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detects if contains textual data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rawData">The raw data.</param>
    public static bool CheckForTextualData(byte[] rawData)
    {
        return CheckForTextualData(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detects if contains textual data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rawData">The raw data.</param>
    /// <param name="start">The start.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The count.</param>
    public static bool CheckForTextualData(byte[] rawData, int start, int count)
    {
        if (rawData.Length < count || count < 4 || start + 1 >= count)
            return true;

        if (CheckForByteOrderMark(rawData, start))
        {
            return true;
        }

        int nullSequences = 0;
        int controlSequences = 0;
        for (var i = start + 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (rawData[i - 1] == 0 && rawData[i] == 0)
            {
                if (++nullSequences > 1)
                    break;
            }
            else if (rawData[i - 1] == 0 && rawData[i] < 10)
            {
                ++controlSequences;
            }
        }

        // is text if there is no null byte sequences or less than 10% of the buffer has control caracteres
        return nullSequences == 0 && (controlSequences <= (rawData.Length / 10));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detects if data has bytes order mark to indicate its encoding for textual data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rawData">The raw data.</param>
    /// <param name="start">The start.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool CheckForByteOrderMark(byte[] rawData, int start = 0)
    {
        if (rawData.Length - start < 4)
            return false;

        if (rawData[start] == 0xef && rawData[start + 1] == 0xbb && rawData[start + 2] == 0xbf)
        {
            // Encoding.UTF8;
            return true;
        }
        else if (rawData[start] == 0xfe && rawData[start + 1] == 0xff)
        {
            // Encoding.Unicode;
            return true;
        }
        else if (rawData[start] == 0 && rawData[start + 1] == 0 && rawData[start + 2] == 0xfe && rawData[start + 3] == 0xff)
        {
            // Encoding.UTF32;
            return true;
        }
        else if (rawData[start] == 0x2b && rawData[start + 1] == 0x2f && rawData[start + 2] == 0x76)
        {
            // Encoding.UTF7;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    Ude.CharsetDetector ude = new Ude.CharsetDetector();
    bool _started = false;


    /// <summary>
    /// If the detection has reached a decision.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The done.</value>
    public bool Done { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detected encoding name.
    /// </summary>
    public string EncodingName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the data contains textual data.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsText { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the file or data has any mark indicating encoding information (byte order mark).
    /// </summary>
    public bool HasByteOrderMark { get; set; }

    List<string> singleEncodings = new List<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Reset()
    {
        _started = false;
        Done = false;
        HasByteOrderMark = false;
        singleEncodings.Clear();
        ude.Reset();
        EncodingName = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detects the encoding of textual data of the specified input data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputData">The input data.</param>
    /// <returns>Detected encoding name</returns>
    public string Detect(Stream inputData)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 16 * 1024;
        const int maxIterations = (20 * 1024 * 1024) / bufferSize;
        int i = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while (i++ < maxIterations)
        {
            int sz = inputData.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
            if (sz <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            Detect(buffer, 0, sz);
            if (Done)
                break;
        }
        Complete();
        return EncodingName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detects the encoding of textual data of the specified input data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputData">The input data.</param>
    /// <param name="start">The start.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The count.</param>
    /// <returns>Detected encoding name</returns>
    public string Detect(byte[] inputData, int start, int count)
    {
        if (Done)
            return EncodingName;
        if (!_started)
        {
            Reset();
            _started = true;
            if (!CheckForTextualData(inputData, start, count))
            {
                IsText = false;
                Done = true;
                return EncodingName;
            }
            HasByteOrderMark = CheckForByteOrderMark(inputData, start);
            IsText = true;
        }

        // execute charset detector                
        ude.Feed(inputData, start, count);
        ude.DataEnd();
        if (ude.IsDone() && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ude.Charset))
        {
            Done = true;
            return EncodingName;
        }

        const int bufferSize = 4 * 1024;

        // singular buffer detection
        if (singleEncodings.Count < 2000)
        {
            var u = new Ude.CharsetDetector();
            int step = (count - start) < bufferSize ? (count - start) : bufferSize;
            for (var i = start; i < count; i += step)
            {
                u.Reset();
                if (i + step > count)
                    u.Feed(inputData, i, count - i);
                else
                    u.Feed(inputData, i, step);
                u.DataEnd();
                if (u.Confidence > 0.3 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Charset))
                    singleEncodings.Add(u.Charset);
            }
        }
        return EncodingName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finalize detection phase and gets detected encoding name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Encoding Complete()
    {
        Done = true;
        ude.DataEnd();
        if (ude.IsDone() && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ude.Charset))
        {
            EncodingName = ude.Charset;
        }
        else if (singleEncodings.Count > 0)
        {
            // vote for best encoding
            EncodingName = singleEncodings.GroupBy(i => i)
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.Count() *
               (i.Key.StartsWith("UTF-32") ? 2 :
               i.Key.StartsWith("UTF-16") ? 1.8 :
               i.Key.StartsWith("UTF-8") ? 1.5 :
               i.Key.StartsWith("UTF-7") ? 1.3 :
               i.Key != ("ASCII") ? 1 : 0.2))
                .Select(i => i.Key).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EncodingName))
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(EncodingName);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
using (var _bookStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    var encoding = FileEncoding.DetectFileEncoding(_bookStream);
    _bookStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var _bookReader = new StreamReader(_bookStream, encoding);
    var _bookContent = await _bookReader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

**Tips**

You may need to add extended character set support, add this in the constructor of `App.xaml.cs`

```cs
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you @Thansy! It worked perfectly and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Comments, it turns out that Notepad .txt and MS Word .txt files use different encoding (UTF-8 without BOM and iso-8859-1 respectively) by default.

The obvious solution would be to demand a *fixed encoding from the input*. Every parser worth their Memory Footprint does that. I do not have a MS Word lying around, but I am going to guess Notepad has the more limited Encoding options with: UTF-8 (with and without BOM), UTF-16 (Big and Low Endian) and ANSI. So one of those should be valid formats.

My general advise is to not work with strings if it can be at all avoided. Arguably string are the second worst format to process. The only thing worse is raw binary. And when parsing .txt files, you are even working with raw binary, to then start working with strings. Strings are a nessesary evil for user input and output. My 3 rules for string processing are:

1. Avoid using string
2. If you can not avoid using string, at least pick a fixed Encoding and culture setting (for text generted from Programm code) for all endpoints. You do not want to add those worries to your list of problems.
3. Existing serialisation approaches like JSON and XML solve 2 for you. XML just anotates the encoding and culture in the file. While JSON afaik has a fixed encoding and culture, everyone adheres to.

If neither fixed encodings or the XML/JSON way are an option, you are down to the age old game of "guess what encoding is this HTML document in". See the [previously linked article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), under `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"`. As a fallback Browser try to guesstimate the encoding, based on Language science. But how much this works depends on what your actuall input is. It does help that you only have two automatic encodings to expect.

Comment: Thank you @Christopher! I've talked to some clients about setting a default encoding for the files. It is the best solution. Anyway, the solution presented by Thansy works very well.